# Solution of cubic equations in terms of quadratic equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, cubics

Is there a general way in which a cubic equation of $3$rd degree can be represented by a quadratic equation of $2$nd degree such that $2$ solutions of a cubic equation is equal to $2$ solutions of corresponding quadratic equation.

For example $2$ solutions of equation $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx-(A+B+C)=0$ is equal to $2$ solutions of quadratic equation $Ax^2+(A+B)x+(A+B+C)=0$.

But here the last term of cubic equation is $-(A+B+C)$.

If the last term is arbitrarily some constant number not equal to $-(A+B+C)$ then what quadratic equation will give the $2$ solution of cubic equation $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0$ such that $D$ is not equal to $-(A+B+C)$

Comment: Cubic equations have $3$ solutions, two of which may be complex. The formulas I know of are rational (involving cube roots and of square roots) or trigonometric. I really don't know what you are asking but a sample equation may help.

Comment: For example a cubic equation is( x^3)-(4x^2) -7x+10=0 has 3 solutions out of which 2 solutions are 5 and -2 and a quadratic equation is (x^2)-(3x)-10=0 it also has same solution 5 and -2 now if we observe the relationship between coefficients of both equations then we can come to conclusion  that roots of cubic equation of form Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx-(A+B+C) and roots of quadratic equation Ax^2+(A+B)+(A+B+C) .will be same now my question is what will be the equivalent quadratic equation if last term of cubic equation is not - (A+B+C)

Comment: Example of other cubic equations and quadratic equation whose solution are same are 100y^2-20y+1 and 100y^3-120y^2+21y-1=0

Answer (score 1):

Given the equation $\quad x^3 - 4x^2 - 7x + 10 = 0 \quad $ we can guess that it has one or more rational roots and, by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), we can "guess" these by using the "factors" or the first and last term. The factors of the last term are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm5,\pm10$ and if we try the first one, we find

$$\quad ( x^3 - 4x^2 - 7x + 10)/(x-1)=x^2 - 3 x - 10\quad$$

From here, it is easy to use the quadratic equation to solve it. On the other hand it is just as easy to try all the factors of $10$ and then find that

$$( x^3 - 4x^2 - 7x + 10)\quad  = \quad (x - 1) (x + 2)(x - 5)  = 0$$

In your other example $\quad 100y^3-120y^2+21y-1=0 \quad$ we have $(y-1)$ as a factor and it also yields a solvable quadratic. In both these equations, one factor must be found before the quadratic can be solved. One way to find the [single] factor to be divided (see synthetic division) is to use the cubic equation. If we use your last equation as an example we have coeficients $\quad a=100\quad b=-120\quad c=21\quad d=-1\quad $ and then

$$x=\sqrt[\Large{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}\\
+\sqrt[\Large{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}-\frac{b}{3a}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a x^3+b x^2+c x-(a+b+c)=0\tag{1}$$
has the integer solution $x=1$ thus can be factored as
$$(x-1)\left[a x^2+(a+b) x+(a+b+c)\right]=0$$
So two soolutions of $(1)$ are solutions of
$$a x^2+(a+b) x+(a+b+c)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Once you find one root of a cubic, you can take out a linear factor by the factor theorem, leaving a quadratic to solve for the other roots. It's not *pretty*, but it works. (The weird part is some *other* quadratics are of interest along the way.)

In analogy with completing the square, divide out the leading coefficient and shifting the unknown to lose the second highest-order term. We want a root of $x^3+px+q=0$. Given any root $x$, some $u,\,v\in\Bbb C$ satisfy $u+v=x,\,uv=-p/3$, namely the roots of $t^2-xt-p/3$. Then$$u^3+v^3=x(x^2-3uv)=x^3+px=-q,\,u^3v^3=(-p/3)^3,$$so $u^3,\,v^3$ are roots of $t^2+qt-p^3/27$. The root we'll take out as aforementioned is $\sum_\pm\sqrt[3]{\frac{-q\pm\sqrt{q^2+4p^3/27}}{2}}$. (Note you have to define these cube roots in just the right way, so their product is $-p/3$; we don't want to be off by a factor of $\exp\tfrac{\pm2\pi i}{3}$.)